# TableView Strange behavior when initializing

Tags: c++, qt, uitableview

TableView in Qt framework is very useful but when it comes to making it empty to refill it again is a little bit hard and strange.

```
QStandardItemModel *emptyModel= new QStandardItemModel(0,0);
emptyModel->clear();
ui->tableViewTraceRoute->setModel(emptyModel);
```

after affecting the emptyModel to the TableView it will not take another model and therefor showing new information.

Comment: How is it not able to take another model? I have working code that is able to change between empty and non-empty model.

Comment: i've told you that this is strange

Comment: Actually I use setModel(nullptr) to set an empty model.